# If $ A,B $ are finite sets and $ | P(A) | = 2 \cdot | P(A \setminus B ) | $ then $ | A \cap B | =1 $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Claim**: If $ A,B $ are finite sets and $ | P(A) | = 2 \cdot | P(A \setminus B ) | $ then $ | A \cap B | =1  $

**Attempt**:
Let $ A,B $ be finite sets.
If $ A = \emptyset $ then $ P( A \setminus B ) = P( \emptyset) = P(A) $ , meaning the claim to prove is vacuously true ( since we have  $ | P(A) | = 2 \cdot | P(A \setminus B ) | = 2 \cdot | P(A)| $ which is false  ).
If $ A \neq \emptyset$,
$~$ If $ B = \emptyset $ then the claim to prove is vacuously true ( since we have  $ | P(A) | = 2 \cdot | P(A \setminus B ) | = 2 \cdot | P(A)| $ which is false ).
$~$ If $ B \neq \emptyset  $. Suppose $ | P(A) | = 2 \cdot | P(A\setminus B) | $. [ From here I got stuck and I don't really know how to continue, maybe I should try assuming $ | A \cap B | \neq 1 $ and try to reach a contradiction?, I don't really see how to reach any contradiction though ]

Anyone got ideas how to prove the claim above? I feel lost... thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** How do we calculate $|P(A)|$?

> If $|A|=a$ and $|A\cap B|=p$ then we have $$2^a=2\cdot 2^{a-p}\implies a=1+a-p$$
> So $p=1$ and we are done.